# .NET Framework 4.6.1 support in SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

From this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx I know that ssrs 2016 is going to support .net framework 4.5.1.

This is a good improvement, since previous versions doesn't support 4.x

**BUT....**

From this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx

We can see that support for .net framework 4.5.1 ended some days ago (january 12th).

**SO...**

My question is: Is SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services going to support .net framework 4.6.1, considering that 4.5.1 isn't supported by Microsoft anymore?

Comment: Is there any specific feature you want to use in 4.6.1?

Comment: My assemblies, which are used by my reports in SSRS, are built under .NET Framework 4.6.1

Thus, the most basic thing I need now is to be able to build and reference them - and use inside my reports.